# How to speed-up the replacement of missing values for each groupby group in Pandas?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a very large pandas dataset, where the data look like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group1' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
                         'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'group2' : ['C', 'C', 'C', 'D',
                         'E', 'E', 'F', 'F'],
                   'B' : ['one', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN,
                        np.NaN, 'two', np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   'C' : [np.NaN, 1, np.NaN, np.NaN,
                        np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 4]})     




df
Out[64]: 
     B   C group1 group2
0  one NaN      A      C
1  NaN   1      A      C
2  NaN NaN      A      C
3  NaN NaN      A      D
4  NaN NaN      B      E
5  two NaN      B      E
6  NaN NaN      B      F
7  NaN   4      B      F
```

Here you can see that, for each unique combination of  `group1` and `group2`, the columns `B` and `C` contain at most one non-missing variable.

**Within each `groupby(['group1','group2'])` group**, I replace all the missing values by using that unique non-missing value (in that group) if that value exists.

To do so, I use the `first` function available after a `groupby`, which propagates the first-non missing value for B or C in each group to the rest of the missing values in that group:

```
df[['B','C']]=df.groupby(['group1','group2']).transform('first')     



df
Out[62]: 
     B   C group1 group2
0  one   1      A      C
1  one   1      A      C
2  one   1      A      C
3  NaN NaN      A      D
4  two NaN      B      E
5  two NaN      B      E
6  NaN   4      B      F
7  NaN   4      B      F
```

Unfortunately this is **painfully slow** on my very large dataset. Do you see any way to improve the speed here? I was thinking about `fillna`, but it seems I would need to apply it twice (`ffill` and `bfill`)... Any ideas?

**UPDATE** Would the very efficient solution proposed by `ajcr` below work with groups defined by several columns? `map` does not work in this case. Maybe `merge`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my machine, it can almost 100 times faster to use `groupby` and then `map`:

```
g = df.groupby('group', sort=False).first()

df['B'] = df['group'].map(g['B'])
df['C'] = df['group'].map(g['C'])
```

Here's a test DataFrame with 1000 groups and 10000 rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': np.repeat(np.arange(1000), 10),
                    'B': np.nan,
                    'C': np.nan})

df.ix[4::10, 'B':'C'] = 5 # every 4th row of a group is non-null
```

And the timings:

```
%%timeit

df2 = df.copy()

g = df2.groupby('group', sort=False).first()

df2['B'] = df2['group'].map(g['B'])
df2['C'] = df2['group'].map(g['C'])
```

This returns `100 loops, best of 3: 2.29 ms per loop`.

The `transform` method is nearly 100 times slower:

```
%%timeit

df3 = df.copy()

df3[['B','C']] = df3.groupby('group').transform('first')
```

This returns `1 loops, best of 3: 205 ms per loop`.

---

Regarding you updated question concerning using multiple groups, @jeff's suggestion in the comments below of using

```
df['B'] = df.groupby(['group1','group2']).B.transform('first')
df['C'] = df.groupby(['group1','group2']).C.transform('first')
```

is about 50 times faster than transforming both columns in one go. This is because currently `transform` is much more performant for Series although there is a [newly-created issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12737) to increase the speed of the operation on DataFrames too.

Comment: genius. lemme try this solution

Comment: can you just explain what is the `map` doing here?

Comment: I was playing with something similar to `a[['B','C']] = a.apply(lambda x: g.loc[x.group, ['B','C']], axis=1)`, but it was much slower. So +1 vote for your solution

Comment: @Noobie: `map` just goes along the values in a column and looks them up in a Series or dictionary (or applies a function) and replaces that value with the value it gets back. In this case, we're using `df['group'].map(g['B'])` to create a new column by replacing group values with the appropriate value in the groupby DataFrame `g`.

Comment: that is great, but will the code work with a groupby done by multiple columns? how would you change the syntax? Say I want to aggregate the missing values by `groupby(['group1,'group2','group3'])`

Comment: huuum that would involve mapping several columns... is that even possible?

Comment: maybe by using a multiindex?

Comment: actually a good old merge with `g` seem to work. what do you think?

Comment: ajcr, I have updated the question following your nice answer. Of course, you deserve the question if it is not possible to adapt your code. Sorry about that, it was difficult to foresee that the multiple groups would be so important here.

Comment: Created an issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12737. The series have a very fast path for this, while the DataFrame path is not so fast. So doing: ``df['B'] = df.groupby('group').B.transform('first'); df['C'] = df.groupby('group').C.transform('first')`` is the most idiomatic/performant ATM.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff - I was surprised that `transform` was significantly slower for the DataFrame here. @Noobie: I think that the solution Jeff suggests best answers your updated question.

Comment: @ajcr yep, fast transform was only implemented for Series groupby's, DataFrame groupbys can be done in a similar way.

Comment: @Noobie: added jeff's suggestion into the answer. For your small example DataFrame I time this to be twice as fast.

Comment: @Alex Riley - 100.77600002288818 seconds using groupby plus bfill (the non-null value's position is known) versus 1.2479996681213379 seconds using groupby then map. Plus one!

Answer (score 1):

Let's speed it up a little bit:

```
In [130]: a = df.copy()

In [131]: %timeit a['B'],a['C'] = a.B.fillna(method='ffill'), a.C.fillna(method='bfill')
1000 loops, best of 3: 538 µs per loop

In [132]: a = df.copy()

In [133]: %timeit a[['B','C']]=a.groupby('A').transform('first')
100 loops, best of 3: 3 ms per loop
```

Comment: thank you maxU but we dont know exactly where is the non-missing value in each group. In other words, doing just a `ffill` on B might not work. That is why I was mentioning a double `ffill` and `bfill` on each column...

Comment: @Noobie, could you please update your sample DF correspondingly?

Comment: actually your code works on the example, but I dont understand why it works. For instance, if you `forward fill` the column B, shouldnt we have one residual missing value? Indeed, the first non-missing value for the B column in the `groupby` B group is on the second row (row 5 in the df)...

Comment: actually, I now notice that your code does not take into account the aggregation at the group level. Missing values have to be replaced within each group. Do you have an other solution in mind? thanks for helping!

Comment: Indeed, your code does not work. I was looking at my output. try for yourself. thanks again!!

Comment: @Noobie, i couldn't find anything faster than ajcr's solution

Answer (score 1):

What if you went about this differently and didn't try and fill, but instead rebuilt?

```
unique_df = df.drop_duplicates()

bVal = unique_df.drop(['B'],axis = 1).dropna().set_index(['A'])
cVal = unique_df.drop(['C'],axis = 1).dropna().set_index(['A'])

colVals = pd.merge(bVal,cVal, how = 'outer',left_index = True, right_index = True)
output = pd.merge(df[['A']],colVals, how = 'left',left_on = 'A',right_index = True)
```

Shrink the df down to the unique parts, find the unique rows on the smaller dataframe, then merge back on to rebuild larger frame - faster?